# Whenever I want to turn off the monitor in Windows 8.1, this code turns my monitors off temporarily then turns back on to the lock screen

Tags: vb.net, windows-8.1

```
'send message implementation
SendMessage(Me.Handle.ToInt32, WM_SYSCOMMAND,
            CType(SC_MONITORPOWER, IntPtr), CType(MonitorShutoff, IntPtr))

'declarations
Private Const MonitorShutoff As Integer = 2
Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
Private Const SC_MONITORPOWER As Integer = &HF170

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hMsg As Integer, _
                      ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Whenever I want to turn off the monitor in Windows 8.1, this code turns my monitors off temporarily then turns back on to the lock screen, how to i avoid the lock screen?
This is only an issue on Windows 8+ systems.  I want my monitors to turn off and stay off. How do i do this?

Comment: You forgot to write a question apparently.

Comment: I want my monitors to turn off and stay off. How do i do that? Sorry for putting things into statements of outcomes instead of question form. I command the.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable a secondary monitor (with ChangeDisplaySettingsEx)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643985/how-to-disable-a-secondary-monitor-with-changedisplaysettingsex)

Comment: what does your `SendMessage` declaration/signature look like?

Comment: Added it to main post

Comment: @Graymatter nope. That is to disable a secondary monitor. If your run the code above, this is clearly not the issue. Reminder: this is only replicable on Windows 8+ systems NOT Windows 7 as the problem is in your link. The second monitor has nothing to do with this issue and has nothing to do with disabling a monitor.

Comment: For previous versions of Windows, using `1` instead of `2` worked for me, but testing it now on Win8.1, `1` does nothing and `2` blanks my machine AND doesn't allow restoration with the move of the mouse or typing on the keyboard! (I've found the fastest way to get back control from this state is to use the Standby keystroke available on my keyboard [turbo]+[Scroll Lock], but before I knew that I had to RDP into my machine from another.)

Comment: And now I've tested it on a Vista laptop: `2` works properly for me, blanking the screen, but not locking it on restoration with the move of the "mouse" or a keypress. `1` never worked, but I assumed that was because it was a laptop...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is working correctly for you. It's just that your mouse is "moving" (or your keyboard is being "touched").

Comment: My mouse and keyboard are not moving as far as I can tell. What should I do?

Comment: That's why I put quotes around "moving": it is likely your mouse has a "jitter" and is moving for the purposes of the check that determines when to restore the display. You can probably confirm this by removing your mouse just before enabling this blanking. Unfortunately your mouse may not work again until restarting (although that's probably no longer the case for USB mice, but I don't know).

Comment: Not that I am aware. I take incredibly good care of my mouse and keyboard. Both are over 100 dollars a piece and I do make mouse drivers professionally.  Have you actually tested my code on a Windows 8.1 computer with success?

Comment: I have again tested my equivalent DotLisp code with Win8.1 and it worked fine this time (i.e. using 2 and it did not forget to allow restoration as I described in the question comments). I tried once and only waited a few seconds before moving the mouse and then again, and did not attempt to restore it for over 30 minutes. Admittedly I was not at the computer for much of that latter time, but I saw no signs of it resuming without me.