# C# - Disable/Enable Display Devices

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to figure out how disable display devices programatically but not having any luck. The closest I have gotten is with this, but none of these flags seem to allow me to disable the monitor, much less re-enable it. Does anyone have any ideas? I referenced [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ChangeDisplaySettingsEx.html) to get this far.

```
[Flags()]
public enum ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags : uint
{
    CDS_NONE = 0,
    CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x00000001,
    CDS_TEST = 0x00000002,
    CDS_FULLSCREEN = 0x00000004,
    CDS_GLOBAL = 0x00000008,
    CDS_SET_PRIMARY = 0x00000010,
    CDS_VIDEOPARAMETERS = 0x00000020,
    CDS_ENABLE_UNSAFE_MODES = 0x00000100,
    CDS_DISABLE_UNSAFE_MODES = 0x00000200,
    CDS_RESET = 0x40000000,
    CDS_RESET_EX = 0x20000000,
    CDS_NORESET = 0x10000000
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern DISP_CHANGE ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(string lpszDeviceName, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode, IntPtr hwnd, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags dwflags, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: I think your answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643985/how-to-disable-a-secondary-monitor-with-changedisplaysettingsex

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that seems specific to C++. It seems I cannot pass NULL to the ChangeDisplaySettingsEx using the interface available with C#. [Here is a pastebin of the code I have](http://pastebin.com/4RN2zq93)

Comment: The article describes the need to write to the registry which is language neutral.

Comment: Yes, but the "answer" to the original question includes an additional call to ChangeDisplaySettingsEx where all NULL parameters are passed. C# does not allow me to do this.

Comment: I know this is forever ago, but you can pass in null by casting a null to the required type, eg `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(null, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)null, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NONE, (IntPtr)null);`