# Switching displays with win32api python library

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I have a computer that has two monitors and one TV connected to it and every time I trying to switch from those two monitors just to the TV it takes me sometimes up to 5 minutes because of all the glitches in Windows 11.

I was wondering if it was possible to automate this process using code. I am playing around with the win32api library in Python but it seems to not be able to change settings of display that is set in settings as "disconnected".

When the TV is set to extend mode I am able to get it's device name (\.\DISPLAY3) and change settings of the display but when I disconnect it there is just no way to change its state back to extend.

I would like it to get it working because Windows is just terrible at changing the display outputs.

Comment: It should be [SetDisplayConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdisplayconfig) or [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsexa). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643985/how-to-disable-a-secondary-monitor-with-changedisplaysettingsex for ChangeDisplaySettingsEx example.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I looked at these functions before but they both takes the device name as argument. The function can't access monitor with it's device name when the monitor is "disconnected".